# newer chrome fails on websocket using haproxy server

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, socket.io, haproxy

test site http://socket.trailsandtribulations.net

firefox: v15 works fine.  (however, if lots of traffic and slow net, firefox will frequently fail as well (quietly).)

chrome: previously worked, but v21 gets `Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'`

*however*, if `chrome` is running locally, it works fine!  it breaks on my client in Thailand and server in Germany.  again, Firefox works correctly all the time, as did earlier versions of chrome.

using `haproxy` to split between websockets via `node.js` and html via `nginx`

has something changed that makes this solution not work?

`haproxy.cfg` now displays the test site link - that way it's always current.

Comment: which versions of Firefox and Chrome ?  There has been several iterations of the Websocket protocol, and some versions have been supported and dropped intermittently.. so maybe your setup works only for certain versions.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support

Comment: @abourget - have added current chrome and firefox versions above.  thanks for the link, but do not understand the whats and whys in this area enough to make a dent, so reliant on the greater knowledge of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firefox uses `no-cache` when requesting the websocket update; this version of chrome does not.  see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148908&thanks=148908&ts=1347523876

for some proxies evidently this is necessary

also, see https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/pull/88 for related issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your message that the error is reported by Chrome while initially I understood it was reported by the server when accessed by Chrome. I think that as a workaround, if you replace "option httpclose" with "option http-server-close", it could make the issue disappear. You also need to remove all "option forceclose". If there is only "option http-server-close", haproxy will not touch the Connection header in the response path, which should make the browser happy. However, you must keep in mind that there is still a bug where the error is displayed and that it should be reported to the software authors.

BTW, your timeouts are far too large, you'll end up with many dead connections at the end of the day, this does not make sense. If you use a recent enough haproxy, you can use "timeout tunnel" to set the WS timeout without having to deal with a large HTTP timeout. But even then, 1 day is far too large for TCP connections. Some of your users will be using smartphones where a TCP connection cannot live more than a few minutes before a handover happens.

Comment: thanks for your response - nice to work with someone who actually knows what's going on.  think followed your directions, but same symptoms.  can see current `haproxy.cfg` in link.  1) any ideas?  2) report to software authors - you mean chrome authors?

Comment: you config looks OK. Well, there is something else you can try, it is to add "option http-pretend-keepalive" in the backends. It will tell you if it's the server which is unhappy with the close value. Concerning software authors, it was not perfectly clear to me where you got the error message, so I was talking about the software emitting this error message which does not comply with the protocol specification.

Comment: the "option http-pretend-keepalive" in either backend breaks websockets entirely.  the "Error during Websocket handshake" originated from chrome; have filed error with them but have not heard back.